# Importing JavaScript files into content scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, vite

I am using Vite.js and making an extension, inside one of my content scripts I need to import an API Client that I'm making, which is in a separate .js file and it's a class with methods.
When I try to import it I get this error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.
I dont know how to make my content script a module..

I tried importing into , tried import with import keyword.